# Update label consecutively using scanner, inJavaFx

Tags: multithreading, javafx, runnable

I'm currently trying to learn JavaFx, and I'm now stuck on a problem. By using a scanner I want to update my label on stage consecutively.

I have tried to use platform.runLater, but this only shows one update. It doesnt update the label every time I write something new in my console.

This is what I have been using:

```
          Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  label.setText(sc.nextLine());
                }
           });
```

Comment: `nextLine()` is a blocking method: you should not call it on the FX Application Thread. You need to use a background thread to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The `nextLine()` method in `Scanner` is a blocking call: you should never block the FX Application Thread. You need to create a background thread to read from the scanner, and then update the label on the FX Application Thread:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UpdateLabelFromScanner extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();

        Thread scannerReadThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine() ;
                    Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText(line));
                }
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        scannerReadThread.setDaemon(true);
        scannerReadThread.start();

        StackPane root = new StackPane(label);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 180, 120));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. One way to is to read the text into an observable property, and when that property changes, you update your label. One of the objects you can use to do this is called [SimpleStringProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html).

Declare it like this:

```
private StringProperty someText = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

In a constructor or some initialization function, add a new [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) to the property:

```
someText.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        label.setText(newValue);
    });
});
```

When you read input from your scanner, change the value of your observable and the listener you added will be invoked, thus changing the text of your label:

```
someText.set(sc.nextLine());
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I'm still getting det same problem. I can only update the label once. I tried to put "someText.set(sc.nextLine());" in to a While where it does it as long as there are input from user, but then the program crashes.